# How can I debug a Windows service that is in a different solution?

Tags: wcf, debugging, windows-mobile

I've got 2 vb.net solutions. One running my client-side code (which runs a Windows mobile application) the other is running my server side code. How can I debug my server-side code (a service) that exists in an entirely different solution?

Comment: Sorry--I was an idiot and realized that the web site is actually in the same solution. I attached to the w3wp.exe process to debug it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From where? If from client code, run your server solution (sln) (via f5), then attach to the host via Debug/Attach to Process in the client sln. Alternatively, You could run both SLN at the same time then but break point in the server.